# How to write this line from keras in tensorflow embedding_sum = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1))(embed)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

How to write this line from keras in tensorflow

```
embedding_sum = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1))(embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layer seems to just do sum over axis 1. In Tensorflow you can do this with `tf.reduce_sum` method:

```
embedding_sum = tf.reduce_sum(embed, axis=1)
```